# Accessing Root in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, path, tree, ipython, jupyter

I've started a notebook from the D:/ drive, but navigated a few directories down. My notebook is at D:/dir1/dir2/notebook.ipynb. In my current notebook, I want to execute a script in the root of D:/, where my notebook session was started from.

I want to avoid relative path changes, and was hoping there's a way to access the directory location of where I had started the notebook (the location corresponding to localhost:xxxx/tree. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a slightly hacky way, but works:

```
import jupyter_core
import os,glob,json

jrd = jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_runtime_dir()
with open(glob.glob(jrd+'/nbserver-*.json')[0]) as json_file:
    root_dir = json.load(json_file)['notebook_dir']
```

The reason for the globbing is because the json file you are looking for has a number corresponding to the process id (PID) in its name.

Therefore this method will be guaranteed to work if you have **only one** notebook instance. If you know the PID you don't need to use `glob`